# How to distinguish responses by mime-type in Django class-based view?

Tags: javascript, python, django, api, rest

In class based view I can define method for `GET` or for `POST`. Can I somehow define special methods for different mime-types of responses?

Use case is - make AJAX site usable even if JS is turned off.

Comment: You could check the `Accept` header of `request.META` to decide which format of response to return and serialize your 'general response' using appropriate serializer to appropriate format. That's similar to what [django-rest-framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/) does.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from myapp.models import Author

class AjaxableResponseMixin(object):
    """
    Mixin to add AJAX support to a form.
    Must be used with an object-based FormView (e.g. CreateView)
    """
    def render_to_json_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        data = json.dumps(context)
        response_kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
        return HttpResponse(data, **response_kwargs)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        response = super(AjaxableResponseMixin, self).form_invalid(form)
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            return self.render_to_json_response(form.errors, status=400)
        else:
            return response

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # We make sure to call the parent's form_valid() method because
        # it might do some processing (in the case of CreateView, it will
        # call form.save() for example).
        response = super(AjaxableResponseMixin, self).form_valid(form)
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            data = {
                'pk': self.object.pk,
            }
            return self.render_to_json_response(data)
        else:
            return response

class AuthorCreate(AjaxableResponseMixin, CreateView):
    model = Author
    fields = ['name']
```

Take a look at this example from the documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#ajax-example

There are two cases: whether the form is valid or not.
from there we have two cases: if the request was AJAX-based or not (request.is_ajax)